# Sending Usage Info and/or crash report to own backend system from iOS apps

Tags: ios

What are the simple ways to send some usage info for debugging along with crash report to the custom backend server. There are applications such as Hockey app, parse and Fabric, but not sure whether they support sending this info to the custom Backend system. I want a simple approach as the requirement is only for debugging purpose, No analytics data required.

Comment: Fabric will give you the details of crash happened in your app to your registered email. From there you can login to fabric and you can see the details of crash.

Comment: This an old but interesting question. I guess the idea was to find solutions that directly send crash reports to the developer without anyone else harvesting user and developer data. Sadly they have become pretty rare.